# Dual monitors - detect if other monitor is on?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I run two separate monitors to the back of my graphics card which happens to accept 2 DVI inputs.  I am running Windows 7.

80% of the time, I just require one monitor on, and just use the 2nd monitor for development work.

The problem I have is that sometimes a window can open on the 2nd monitor.
The workaround is to windows key + left arrow to bring it onto the other monitor.

Is there a way for my NVidia graphics card/Windows 7 to automatically understand that the other monitor is powered down, and thus just extend the desktop to the border of the primary monitor that is turned on?

Comment: I'm not sure about automatically detecting it, but you can use Windows+P to pull up the display switcher applet. Your video card driver also might let you configure a hotkey to switch between display modes (e.g., switch between extend and clone, or extend and single).

Comment: @rob: I've been using that for a long time now, but it's not bulletproof either. I've had applications start on my "ghost" second monitor even when it's not connected. That was before W7 and the Windows+Left/Right arrow.

Comment: Some video card drivers and utilities also allow you to force new windows to open on a specific monitor...perhaps that would suit your needs.

Comment: To add to Rob's comment, do you have [nView](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nview_display_us.html) installed?  Right click on the desktop, and select `nView Properties`.  Enable nView if not already enabled, then check out the Windows tab.  I've tried `Prevent windows from opening off-screen` without success.  As Rob said, you can also change `Open windows on` to your primary display.  Will that work?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/), which adds a lot of multimonitor functionality that probably should already be in Windows but isn't. I'm guessing that for your purposes I blieve you'd have to get the Pro version- which is a $25 that I found to be well spent. The free version is a must have for anyone running a multimonitor Windows setup IMHO.

Comment: Agree wholeheartedly. You can try the full version for 30 days. I used it all of 5 minutes before I decide to buy it.